# Python replace value in text file

Tags: python, search, replace

I'm trying to replace a value in a specific line in a text file.

My text file contains count of the searchterm, searchterm & date and time

Text file:

```
MemTotal,5,2016-07-30 12:02:33,781
model name,3,2016-07-30 13:37:59,074
model,3,2016-07-30 15:39:59,075
```

How can I replace for example the count of the searchterm for line 2 (`model name,3,2016-07-30 13:37:59,074`)?

This is what I have already:

```
f = open('file.log','r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

newdata = filedata.replace("2", "3")

f = open('file.log', 'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

It replace all values `2`.

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Please show your efforts and what code you have so far.

Comment: What is the rule to replace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change three things in your code to get the job done:

1. Read the file using `readlines`.

   ```
   filedata = f.readlines()
   ```
2. Modify the line you want to change (keep in mind that Python indices start at 0 and don't forget to add a newline character `\n` at the end of the string):

   ```
   filedata[1] = 'new count,new search term,new date and time\n'
   ```
3. Save the file using a for loop:

   ```
   for line in filedata:
       f.write(line)
   ```

Here is the full code (notice I used the `with` context manager to open/close the file):

```
with open('file.log', 'r') as f:
    filedata = f.readlines()

filedata[1] = 'new count,new search term,new date and time\n'

with open('file.log', 'w') as f:
    for line in filedata:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
count = 0
line_number = 0
replace = ""
f = open('examen.log','r')
term = "MemTotal"
for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if term in line:
                replace= line.replace("5", "25", 1)
                line_number = count
        count = count + 1
print line_number
f.close()
f = open('examen.log','r')
filedata = f.readlines()
f.close()

filedata[line_number]=replace+'\n'
print filedata[line_number]
print filedata
f = open('examen.log','w')
for line in filedata:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

You only need to define the searchterm & the replace value